# Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, boolean, observable, store

I do not know what should i do can anyone help me please

I made the reducer and added the cases

but my problem is when I connect the reducer with the observable
it keep telling me
Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

but when i changed it to void it dose not also work

sorry for the bad english

here is the code

```
import { Component, OnDestroy , OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthsService } from '../auths.service';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/shared/ui.service';
import { Subscription,Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromRoot from '../../app.reducer';
import * as fromLoading from '../../shared/load.reducer'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private Authservice: AuthsService, private fb: FormBuilder, private uiService: UiService,
    private Stoore: Store<{ui:fromLoading.State}>
  ) { }
  private loadingSub: Subscription;
  
  isloading$:  Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.isloading$ = this.Stoore.pipe(map(state => { state.ui.theLoading }));
                                

    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    })

  }

  
  


  onSubmit() {
    this.Authservice.login({
      email:this.loginForm.value.email,
      password:this.loginForm.value.password
    })
  }
}
```

the reducer code

```
export interface State {
   theLoading: boolean;
}

const initialState: State = {
   theLoading:false
}

export function LoadingReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'START_LOADING':
         return {
            theLoading: true,
         }
      
      case 'STOP_LOADING':
         return {
            theLoading:false
         }
      
      default :
         return {
            state
         }
   }
}
```

I want to store it in

this.isloading$ = this.Stoore.pipe(map(state => { state.ui.theLoading }));

but it keep telling me

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Comment: just add a return here: `state => { return state.ui.theLoading }`  or even better you could remove the curly brackets : `state =>  state.ui.theLoading`